# What is the rule for the sum of matrices multiplied by the transpose of their sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Let's say we have the  expression (XW + e) where each of the terms can be matrices and we want to multiply it by its transpose so that we have (XW+e)*(XW+e)'.

It seems that it works similarly to polynomial expansion for power of 2. We get

XWW'X' + 2XWe' + ee'.

Why is it so and what is the rule here?

Comment: Ultimately, Matrices will carryout mutliplicaiton and addition element-wise. so you can think of them as rows and columns of polynomial equations packed into matrices. Also after carrying out element-wise mutliplicaiton and addition they are repackaged into matrices.

Comment: @PcumP_Ravenclaw I was thinking something like this, but just needed to re-check because I didn't find an explicit rule for this. Why do we have 2XWe' instead of 2XWe, for example? In (a+b)**2 we would have a**2 + 2ab + b**2

Comment: @kirgol For two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size, in general, $(A+B)^2 \neq A^2+2AB+B^2$, because multiplication of matrices is not commutative. Instead, $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$, where the middle two terms might not be equal due to lack of commutativity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me pick the middle two terms $eW'X' + XWe'$. If the two terms result in scalar values then we could take transpose of the two or either one of the terms. so I will take transpose of the first term $(eW'X')' = XWe'$ and this is same as the 2nd term so they could add together to form $2XWe'$

Comment: thank you, now it's clear